# Angular 6 on Internet Explorer -- Angular Material/ Flex layout won't center?

Tags: css, angular-material, internet-explorer-11, angular6, angular-flex-layout

I have a table inside a div that looks like this:

```
  <div fxLayout="row" class="container" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
```

No related CSS -- I have tried various things but in internet explorer, where I have to use polyfills for anything to work anyway, it will simply refuse to center.

I've found a similar stackoverflow thread but the alignment of the items inside the div was different and didn't really apply to my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up wrapping my whole app in app.component.html like this:

```
<div class="container"
         fxLayout="column">
    <div>
      <app-navigation></app-navigation>
    </div>
    <div fxFlexAlign="center" id="routerOutletDiv">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then, in my component that I'm trying to center things, my main div where I wrap ALL other divs has the following:

```
<div fxFlexAlign="center" class="container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="15px">
```

Whilst most of the divs inside this 'parent' have the following:

```
<div fxFill class="item">
```

And some of them that had more items inside them, have the following:

```
<div fxFill fxLayoutAlign="center" class="item">
```

Also ended up adding `fxLayoutAlign="center"` to text that had icons inside it, it didn't want to center otherwise. But I did not have to add extra css or touch other properties.